# Weird network troubles in 14.10

Tags: network-manager, 14.10, iwlwifi

After hours of research I need some help. /:

After upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10 I'm seeing the

```
Waiting for network configuration
```

message on boot, even though my /etc/network/interfaces just contains

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

On boot my network manager doesn't start, I need to start it manually.

When it's running, wired connection works, but wireless is really unstable – both always show a question mark next to the "connected" info.

Sometimes it works after a `pkill wpa_supplicant`, but disconnects after a while again.

My dmesg gives me different messages:

```
deauthenticating from … by local choice (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)

deauthenticating from … by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)

init: networking post-stop process (…) terminated with status 100

init: networking pre-start process (…) terminated with status 1
```

Additionally I have eth1 and wlan1 instead of 0.

Something seems pretty messed up, I found descriptions of some single problems, but never in combination.

I'm using a Thinkpad T430s, it has the Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205 AGN chipset.

How would I continue with this?

Can I reinstall the kernel module somehow?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Another check: latest firmware is installed.

Comment: Just understood that network manager starts on the "static-network-up" event, which is not fired – confirmed by the boot message.

Answer (score 0):

This might be [Ubuntu bug 1408963](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1408963).

I suspect my issue, which appears the same as yours, is one of competing network managers.  In my case, `wicd` and `network-manager`.  Even though I only had one of them running in my system tray (`nm-applet`, the GNOME front end to `network-manager`), I'd still mysteriously lose my connection every once in a while.

My previous "solution" was to keep restarting `network-manager` and then waiting to see if the renegotiated connection lasted more than ~10 seconds, but sometimes that resulted in a loop of 5-10 iterations, and sometimes I'd also need to run `rmmod` on each of the kernel modules starting with "iw" (in the proper order to not muck with dependencies).  That would be between stopping and starting:

```bsh
# old solution, often requires several tries
service network-manager stop
rmmod iwlwifi
rmmod iwldvm
modprobe iwldvm iwlwifi
service network-manager start
```

Reading the above bug made me think that it might be dueling network managers.  So far, things look good after having stopped `wicd`:

```
service wicd stop
```

`network-manager` should automatically take back control and renegotiate your connection in a few seconds.

That said, I don't know how to reproduce this issue without merely waiting an undetermined amount of time, so this might be a bit preliminary.